# Unresolved import in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, import

I'm getting unresolved import lines below these 3 lines of code, and I do not know what to do to get rid of them.

```
import pyautogui 

import win32api, win32con

import keyboard
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `pywin32`, `pyautogui`, and `keyboard`.  Those are not built-in.  Visual Studio has options to install packages for whatever Python you're using.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019